# Javascript how do you use the / symbol

Tags: javascript, symbols

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

i found this and i was wondered what the / sign meant in the `if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}` code.

Comment: [Regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```
/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

It returns true if `navigator.userAgent` contains the pattern above.

Comment: what do you mean contains the pattern? do you mean if it contains "Android" or "webOS" etc in the navigator.userAgent string?